# Assign IP address to database server

Tags: odbc, integration, tally

I have a database currently running on localhost. I want to access it over the internet, but I don't know how to access and change its settings. I can only use ODBC mechanism to connect to it not SQL server. Please suggest a working link for the problem. Thanks in advance to respected community members.

Comment: You need purchase IP, else IP will change every time you reconnect to internet

Comment: If you are talking about Tally, then its bad idea to expose tally to world, as Tally as no authentication, everyone can see, delete and alter your tally data

Comment: i want to access it from my website which loads data from it . so the requirement is for my website .